# How to Join Multiple Tables on any matching characters on any columns of any table with fully unstructured string column?

Tags: sql, string, join, multiple-columns, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to join table1 containing completely unstructured strings with table2, table3, table4. Tables 2, 3 & 4 are the information-supplement tables for table1.
Table1 has just one column with completely unstructured strings which has a lot of information but stored unorganized. tables 2, 3, 4 has to be joined with any few matching characters anywhere in the string of table1.

Imagine texts in the column of table1 is written by a child learning english language, there is no correct spelling of even country names. For example sometimes 'China' is written as 'Chaina' or 'CHN' or 'CHNA', 'Germany' is written as 'Jermeny' or 'GER' or 'GMNY').

Example of the string in table1:
Row1:

```
B12A cscs 901546 B12A alpha hilex a s d v El Margues Queretaro Cloth Set 99810 3NF0A 9981 Chaina Cover Case A0H45 112211 Alpha Corporation China Beiging
```

(There are more than 5 million rows like this, values in example are replaced with random values for organizational data confidentiality).

example of rest of the tables I want to join with table1 in Snowflake environment:
[image]

The way I tried may not be much helpful here.

Here is an example of output I want:
[image]
Can anyone please help to join them efficiently?

Comment: What does using PostgreSQL in Snowflake mean?

Comment: Hey Gordon, I meant the SQL in Snowflake interface (not specifically PostGRES).

Comment: It would help to know the structure (DDL) of the 4 tables mentioned in this question.

Comment: Hi Luuk, They values are strings in all the tables.

Comment: Sounds like you want a join condition of `LENGTH(originalString) > TRANSLATE(originalString, '.'||findString, '.')` (oracle syntax/functionality)